# Download/files management software for clients for website

Tags: wordpress, web, download, software-distribution

I've got different versions of a software that I'd like to distribute to clients (B2B). For example, one might be the base version, an extended version, and a trial version. These would be separate zip files. They are versioned as well.

These files are made available to clients either for trial or after they sign up for a license, and different licenses would give them access to different variants of the "software" (it's not exactly a software, it's just a file, but it doesn't matter for the sake of this question).

Putting these files on a webserver and allow password-protected HTTP access is not ideal as it doesn't allow a fine-grained enough permission model, e.g. for example I may want to give one client access to an update or a beta version, and not to another, and I'd end up creating a separate folder for each client for each version, which is very messy and means duplication a lot of files.

I guess what I am looking for is some simple, web-based "download portal" software, where I can create a web account for each customer. Ideally this would support the concept of "release channels" or something like that, and I could then assign each customer to a release channel, and to specific files in addition to that, to steer which customer has access to which files. I am using a self-hosted WordPress for the main website so I was thinking it would be great to have such a portal on a sub-domain like `download.company.com` and it ideally would use the WordPress authentication mechanism.

I don't want to program such a software myself though and I also didn't find an existing WP plugin that would do something like that. I am mentioning WP but this is not a WP-question, I am looking for any (good) solution - if it was able to use the WP-authentication mechanism, it would just be a really useful feature.

Does any solution like this exist? How would I best go about it? It seems that any B2B company distributing files and/or software to customers would have this problem. Do they all develop their own solution?

I wasn't 100% sure whether this fits on the StackOverflow, SuperUser, WebApps or Webmasters sites, if it's not appropriate here, I am happy to be directed to the most appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

you can do as follow:

- create a redirect scripts page that have the file id ( or filename or whatever) as arguments, for example `download.php?id=2432` or as POST value
- in that page you can check if user is logged in and if that users has the permission to download the file, for example you can have a table with a row with user_id and file_id, if that row exist the user can download the file
- download using php hiding the real url

```
// your validation
if($isUserValid)
{
    $path = $fileName;
    $size = filesize($path);
    $fp = fopen($path, "rb");
    $content = fread($fp, $size);
    fclose($fp);

    header("Content-length: ".$size);
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename="YOURFILEPATH" );
    echo $content;
}
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. That's pretty much a self-made solution. I was hoping there would be something more "out of the box".

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite, stupid simple and free is XODA
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xoda/files/xoda/
It is a stupid simple "CMS" document manager we've used for years.
Our subscriber only information is posted by FTP to each users folder, they simply log in and fetch them.

If you are looking for "all that" go with OwnCloud or NextCloud